# Change UILabel text of custom UIView doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, xib

I have a custom `UIView` which was build with xib that have a file owner called `CustomModuleUIView` which contains labels and buttons . I have called this custom view in my Rootviewcontroller and I succeeded to display it using `initWithCoder` method. The problem is that I can't change the default text of `UILabel` neither from `customMouleUIView` nor from the root `ViewController`. I found example that tells me to do custom initialisation in in `initWithCoder` but it doesn't work for me and nothing changes and without any error it displays the default text.

This is my custom UIView xib
[image]

This is my root view controller
[image]

This is my code oh custom UIView .h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ModuleCustomUIView : UIView

-(void) setup;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *_moduleIcon;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *_moduleName;
- (IBAction)openDemo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *_moduleImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *_positionLabel;

@end
```

code of .m , i use setup method to init my UIView because I couldn't call

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:xib owner:self options:nil] ;
```

inside initWithCoder that causes infinite loop .

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setup
{
    NSString *xib= @"CustomUIView";
    NSArray *array=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:xib owner:self options:nil] ;
    UIView *view =[array objectAtIndex:0];
    //code that doesn't work
    [_positionLabel setText:@"hello world"];
    //
    [self addSubview:view];
}
```

this is my root view controller .h

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_moduleCustomView setup];
    [self.view addSubview:_moduleCustomView];
    //code doesn't work 
    [_moduleCustomView setText:@"hello world"];
}
```

even in the did load I can't change the text

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Did you link the label in the xib to the respective IBOutlet in the view controller?

Comment: i can't add comment now only after 8 hours that 's what stackoverflow tells me .

Comment: i have linked the xib and the label with IB in the file owner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found my mistake , it's about file owner , i have change it in the inspector but by selecting the uiview and not te file's owner , i change NSObject to my class name and reconnect the label .

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Files Owner attribute should be your 'root viewcontroller'.

Comment: i can't link xib based on UIView with a UIViewController i think ?

Comment: sorry misread... have you tried `[view.positionLabel setText:@"hello world"];` in your setup method? Or `[_moduleCustomView.positionLabel setText:@"hello world"];` in your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: yes , this what i have done without any change , yesterday i try awakeFromNib method and i can change it but i want to edit it dynamically .